# Solr Indexing by URLDataSource - How to add headers in request url

Tags: solr, content-type

I want to index a xml that i retrieve from a url using URLDataSource.

The data-config file snippet is below :

```
<dataSource type="URLDataSource" readTimeout="100000"  />
<document>
    <entity processor="XPathEntityProcessor" url="${dataimporter.request.url}"
```

The url requires a content-type:application/json to be added in the header.

Does any one have any idea regarding how to add a header to the url request?

Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar issue.  We are using a .Net Web API service as a data source for our collection and need to tell the service to give us XML instead of JSON (Web API's default).  Ideally we would leave the service in its vanilla state, i.e. not changing its default serializer.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?